# Is hook_translated_menu_link_alter() thought to be used only on translated menu links?

Tags: routes, hooks

Could `hook_translated_menu_link_alter()` be implemented to simply alter a menu link before it is rendered?

Clearly, `hook_translated_menu_link()` is only invoked for menu items that have been flagged from `hook_menu_link_alter()` as altered; if a module uses `hook_translated_menu_link()` to alter a menu item before it is rendered, it needs to implement `hook_menu_link_alter()` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel), it uses `hook_translated_menu_link()` along with `hook_menu_link_alter()` to add a destination query to the end of a few of the links.

http://drupalcode.org/project/devel.git/blob/0ca6cc9bd5e2cf650717b73e8938b88726d0ebbd:/devel.module

- Line #331 - devel_menu_link_alter()
- Line #342 - devel_translated_menu_link_alter()